# Asp.Net: Restoring client-side SelectedItem of DropDownList on server-side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback

So I have a dropDownList on my page that contains hundreds of items. The user can filter this DDL by typing some text into a textbox. The DDL then gets filtered accordingly (all items that do not contain the entered text are removed via JavaScript). The user then selects his item and presses a button. Usually, this would cause an error because the DDL has been altered and ASP validates the PostBack data. However, with `EnableEventValidation="false"`
you can turn off this behavior and the page gets submited properly. But (and thats my problem): the SelectedIndex of the DDL is always "0" on server-side and thus the SelectedItem is the wrong one. So obviously, the changes on client-side are dismissed. Does anybody have an idea on how to get the correct SelectedItem? Or a better way to filter a DDL and maintain the correct SelectedItem?

Comment: Can you post the code to how you are loading and manipulating the DDL.  Typically the postback doesn't care if you manipulate the ddl items as long as it can match up to an expected valid value server side after the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user presses a button get current value of dropdown using jQuery and set it in hidden field on page , give hidden field runat="server" so that when it posts back you will get value that was selected. 
For example

```
    <asp:DropDownList class="myList"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button class="btn"/> 
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnSelectedI" runat="server" class="hiddenControl"> 

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn").click(function(){

      var selectedItem = $(".myList").val();
      $(".hiddenControl").val(selectedItem);  

    });

});
```

I have used clas name selector as ids in aspnet are auto generated. On server side get value of 
`hdnSelectedItem.Value` , and from that pull from list of items/db maintained on server.

Comment: Thanks, this would be a nice workaround. Through trying this solution, I've found a bug in my JS code which causes the DDL options to lose their values --> the postback data was wrong --> the selectedIndex was wrong. Now it works fine without the workaround.