# ASP.NET dropdownlist is empty in server button_click, the ddl is populated client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I've a form to change some address information. When putting some `generic ZIP code` in a text box a client event is fired to populate a dropdownlist with compatible cities.

The populate is correct, the problem is no matter which value I select after, because when I click on the button to save the data, that dropdownlist in server function `button_click` have `SelectedItem to null`, have aso list Items count to 0..

I've put another dropdownlist just for test, with some random cities in it, and if I set a value on it by the same jquery function I can correctly see it in the server function, so the problem seems to be with the fact that the other is populated client side..

I've seen this: [Asp.Net: Restoring client-side SelectedItem of DropDownList on server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558382/asp-net-restoring-client-side-selecteditem-of-dropdownlist-on-server-side) and the set hidden field value workaround, but I was wondering if there's a more correct way to do this..

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Address</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" CssClass="testo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Province</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProvince" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>City</label><br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>ZIP</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtZIP" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Just for test set ddl by jQuery -->
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server"
                OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(function () {

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input[id*="txtZIP"]', function () { 
        var input = $(this);
        if (input[0].selectionStart == 5) {
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "CleanAddress.aspx/txtZIP_TextChanged",
                data: "{ZIP:'" + input.val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var cities = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response.d)); 
                    if (comuni.length > 0) {
                        $("[id*=txtProvince]").val(cities[0].ID_PROVINCE);
                        $("[id*='ddlCity']").empty();
                        $.each(cities, function (key, value) {
                            $("[id*='ddlCity']").append($("<option />
").val(value.ID_CITY).text(value.CITY));
                        });
                        $("[id*='ddlCity']").removeAttr('disabled');
                        $("[id*='ddlTest']").val(9); // Just for test
                        $("[id*='ddlComuneDom']").val(cities[0].ID_CITY);
                        //alert($("[id*='ddlTest']").val());
                        //alert($("[id*='ddlCity']").val());
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Errore! " + result.status + " - " + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
    });

[WebMethod]
    public static List<Comuni> txtZIP_TextChanged(string ZIP)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Cities> cities = new List<Cities>();
            if ((ZIP.Trim() != "") && (ZIP.Length == 5))
            {
                dcListCitiesDataContext dc = new dcListCitiesDataContext();

                if (dc.Cities.Where(c => c.ZIP.Equals(ZIP)).Count() > 0)
                {
                    string province = dc.Cities.Where(c => c.ZIP.Equals(ZIP)).First().ID_PROVINCE.ToUpper();
                    if (province != null)
                    {
                        cities = dc.Cities.Where(c => c.ZIP.Equals(ZIP)).ToList();
                        return cities;
                    }

                }
            }
            return cities;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.WriteLog("CleanAddress - txtZIP_TextChanged " + " - " + ex.Message, TipoLog.Error);
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Here I've always ddlCity empty
    string cities= "";
    if (ddlCity.SelectedItem != null)
        cities= ddlCity.SelectedItem.ToString();
    else
        cities= ddlTest.SelectedItem.ToString();
    (...)
}
```

Comment: To get current selected Text, you should do `$('#dropDownId :selected').text();`

Comment: I want that value server side, and client side the selector #idValue is not valid, rather '<%= dropDown.ClientID %>' or $("[id*='dropDownId']").

Answer (score 0):

In asp webforms you should never add to server side controls on the client side. Because of the abstractions applied like view state, it won't work very well and can cause really fun issues.

If you need to populate the list the "web forms" way you would generally place the dropdownv in an update panel, and load it by doing a partial postback. Then you could add to the items, or do data binding on the server side to populate it.

Of you don't like this option, make it a standard select, and don't try to use the server side control. When you submit your form you should still be able to get the submitted value, and it will be much cleaner.

Comment: The entire page is in an update panel and the first of your option is how it's worked until now, but the dropdown was reloaded changing the ZIP textbox or changing the province textbox, and viceversa, so even if partial all that postbacks results in an "heavy" interface, also because the web application I'm working on show a box with a wheel that turns every postback, that's why I'm moving to jQuery. The standard select is a good idea, but I've other portions of code in the page wich refer to that dropdown, so I think I'm going to the mentioned HiddenField workaround, seems more rapid..

Comment: I can tell you you will end up with exceptions if view state is on. It's a really bad idea. Make the update panels smaller to minimize the amount transferred in each partial postback. The larger they are, the larger the response size. If it is the full page it won't really be a partial update.

Comment: My bad.. I was wrong, I mean not the entire page but the entire user control, that contains the address fields..

Answer (score 0):

As I see in this:

[Asp.Net: Restoring client-side SelectedItem of DropDownList on server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558382/asp-net-restoring-client-side-selecteditem-of-dropdownlist-on-server-side)

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCity" runat="server" />
```

in ZIP text change and in ddl change:

```
$("[id*='hdnCity']").val($("[id*='ddlCity'] option:selected").text());
```

and server side:

```
city = hdnCity.Value;
```